# useMutation status is always 'idle' and 'isLoading' always 'false' - react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-query, react-custom-hooks

So I use react-query to handle API requests. Current problem is that when i try to submit form data, post request, mutation state is always idle, and loading is always false. I also use zustand for state management.

This is useSubmitFormData hook. Post request executes as expected, just mutation status and isLoading does not get changed.

```
export const useSubmitFormData = () => {
  const { postDataPlaceholder } = usePlaceholderApi();
  // data which is submiting is getting from the store - reducer
  const { data, filesToUpload } = useFormDataStore();

  const { mutate, status, isLoading } = useMutation(() => postDataPlaceholder({ data }), {
    onMutate: () => console.log('onMutate', status),
    onSuccess: (res) => console.log(res),
    onError: (err) => console.log('err', err),
  });

  return {
    submitForm: mutate,
    isLoading,
  };
};
```

Now on FormPage.jsx it is triggered like this:

```
const { submitForm, isLoading } = useSubmitFormData();

const onSubmit = () => submitForm();
```

And this is how usePlaceholderApi looks like. It is kind of custom hook in purpose to use axios in combination with interceptors to handle authorization token.

```
const usePlaceholderApi = () => {
  const { post } = usePlaceholderAxios();

  return {
    postDataPlaceholder: async (data) => post('/posts', { data }),
  };
};

export default usePlaceholderApi;
```

And this is usePlaceholderAxios.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const usePlaceholderAxios = () => {
  axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
    const api = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

    if (config.url.indexOf('http') === -1) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      config.url = `${api}${config.url}`;
    }

    return config;
  });

  return {
    get: (url, config) => axios.get(url, config),
    post: (url, data, config) => axios.post(url, data, config),
  };
};

export default usePlaceholderAxios;
```

Any ideas what could go wrong here ? Am I missing something ? Also tried to call axios directly in mutation, without usePlaceholderApi hook in between, but same outcome.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox demo of this code for us to inspect and debug live?

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong with the code, so a codesandbox reproduction would be appreciated

Comment: @connecticut96 I have the same issue here, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve exactly the same problem by creating a flow of hooks.
In my case, I changed importing two separated hooks into one hook.

From this

```js
const { tasks, createTask, deleteTask } =
    useMutateTask()

  const { handleSubmit, onSubmit, register } =
    useTaskForm()
```

To this

```js
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    onSubmit,
    register,
    tasks,
    createTask,
    deleteTask,
  } = useTaskForm()
```